# How to create a Side Panel using the Firebug API?

Tags: api, firebug

Firebug.Panel can be used to create a new panel in the main Firebug window. I am wondering how to create a Side Panel for the HTML main panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by what the side panels built into Firebug are doing, I believe it should just be a matter of adding `parentPanel: "html"` to the panel.